# How to set up value for serial type in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a primery key in my table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    valuea citext NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT a_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
);
```

Table had the following rows:

```
id value
198  b
199  j
```

By accident I did this insert

```
Insert Into a(id,valuea) values (200,'hello');
```

Now, when I try to do another insert in the correct way:

```
Insert Into a(valuea) values ('b');
```

I expect it to insert (201,b) but the serial counter doesn't know 200 has been used because of the last manual insert.

I get:

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "a_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (id)=(200) already exists.

I understand this error.. basically it happens because my last insert was not used the Serial and therefore it's counter didn't rise up.

What I don't know is how to fix it?

How do I tell the serial counter to start from 201?

Comment: Don't manually maintain your auto increment column.  You're not as smart as Postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the sequence name, normally something like `<your table>_id_seq` and do :

```
ALTER SEQUENCE a_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Comment: I know that.. but this is Serial Not actual defined sequence. How do I address it? it doesn't have a name other than the column name.

Comment: @avi: a `serial` creates a sequence in the background

Comment: A serial create a sequence behind the scene. you can list you're sequence by doing : `SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S'`

Comment: @avi When you create Serial column the sequence  define as : `CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;`   so Remi gave you the actual answer.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a `serial` key, Postgres creates a sequence that it uses to generate next values.

Just find that sequence and modify its `START` value to e.g  201 .

`SELECT setval(<name of the sequence>, 201, true);`